# Controls styles not found in MahApps 1.1.3-alpha225

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I was using the stable version on nuget and changed to 1.1.3-alpha225 also from nuget. I did that so I could call dialogs through the ViewModel. But now I'm getting this error:

```
An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml"
```

All other dictionaries are ok:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
```

The controls is the only one giving error:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml"
```

Does anyone know if it changed on the new version or if there's a known bug?

Comment: I have the same problem but with stable version of mahapps and occur when adding cefsharp package to my app. I can build and execute.

Comment: @RBasniak can you open an issue at MahApps GitHUb repo with a complete stack trace and some source code where this exception come from? thx

Comment: @punker76 Ok, I'll do this later today. Thanks